# properly prevent an event emit in an html input

Tags: angular

I have this scenario. One component hold an input where the user type. Another component get the data as the user type and display a list of stuff based on a logic. Here's a simplified example:

```
<input type="text" #itemSearch (input)="inputChange(itemSearch.value)" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)">
```

Relatives functions:

```
inputChange(value: string){
    this.commonService.setToolsToSearch(value);
}

onKeyDown(event: any){
   const code = event.keyCode;
   if(code == 38 || code == 40 || code == 37 || code == 39){
    //    event.stopPropagation();
   }
}
```

the data showed is in a custom list, and I've added this code to let the user interact with it:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      if(event.keyCode == 38){ // arrow up
          //stuff that moves up the selected item by -1
      } else if(event.keyCode == 40){ // arrow down
         // stuff that moves up the selected item by 1
      }
  }
```

So basically using the arrow keys (up and down) the user can "navigate" in this list.

The problem: pressing `up` and `down` needs to execute this logic, but the event that is fire in the input box has to be stopped. Why? Because using the arrow keys moves up the line cursor into the input so if I execute this logic:

- Type 'hello'
- use three times arrow up
- type 'world'

what I get into the input is "heworldllo".

My question is, how to properly stop this event?

As in the code above I tried using `event.stopPropagation();` but nothing changes. Using, instead `event.preventDefault();` does kinda what I need, because it stop the arrow keys to move up the cursor into the input box, but also it doesn't allow the user to use the arrows key to navigate into the list. I believe that acting this way the problem is a `focus` one, because if I click the list then I'm able to use the arrow key to navigate the list. So I've tried to programmatically focus the list, but nothing changed.

Anyone has an idea on how to fix thix?

**EDIT** Solved using `event.preventDefault();` | Thank you @ConnorsFan

simplified working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhkemy

Comment: The `@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])` is on the main component, where the list is situated. I can show you the logic that let the list work as the key are pressed but I believe is useless since the problem is not something about the list. I can even do a `console.log` when I catch the key pressed in the main component, the logic error still persists.

Comment: could you please provide a stackblitz ?

Comment: Using `event.preventDefault()` appears to work (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euqpsh)). Am I missing something?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yep, now is working on mine too. Just no idea why before it just didn't.